# Chain complex of de Rham cohomology for $\mathbb{C}P^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-topology

I am reviewing de Rham [cohomology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Rham_cohomology), so I picked an example complex projective space, $\mathbb{C}P^2$.  Even before I compute the cohomology *groups*  I need to make sure I understand the chain complexes.

$$ 1 \stackrel{d}{\to} \Omega^0(M) \stackrel{d}{\to} \Omega^1(M) \stackrel{d}{\to}\Omega^2(M) \stackrel{d}{\to} 1 $$

- What could be the $0$-forms, <del>those are the constants.</del> those are functions $f: \mathbb{C}P^2 \to \mathbb{R}$.
- The only reasonable $1$-forms I can think of are $dx, dy, dz$ .  Perhaps I have to say $f(x) \, dx$ etc.
- The area forms should be: $ f\, \big( dx \wedge dy\big), g\, \big( dy \wedge dz\big), h \big( dz \wedge dx \big) $ .
- There should be no 3-forms.

My chain complex looks like this (I may have confused the [exterior algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra) and the spaces of [differential forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form))  These notations are nearly right, a $2$-form is a map $\omega : T_p^*(M)\to \mathbb{R}$, so here I'm just writing the [cotangent spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form#Intrinsic_definitions):

$$ 1 \to \langle  dx,  dy, dz \rangle \to \langle dx \wedge dy,\; 
dy \wedge dz,\; dz \wedge dx \rangle \to 1 $$

Then start questions like, are the 1-forms in my $\Omega^1$ space independent?  Should I say that $\Omega^{-1} = 1$.  And more problems:

$$ \mathbb{C} P^2 = 
\{ [x:y:z] : x,y,z \in \mathbb{C}\}/\mathbb{C}^\times $$

So my the forms I have written are not elements of $\Omega^1(\mathbb{C}P^2)$.  Instead I have written the 1-forms for $\mathbb{C}^3$.  Here is my revised version:

$$ 1 \to \big\langle \frac{dx}{x}, \frac{dy}{y}, \frac{dz}{z} \big\rangle \to \big\langle \frac{dx}{x} \wedge \frac{dy}{y},\; 
\frac{dy}{y} \wedge \frac{dz}{z},\; \frac{dz}{z} \wedge \frac{dx}{x} \big\rangle \to 1 $$

One question I have is what these numbers are measuring.  Certainly if we have:

$$ \frac{dx}{x} = d  \big( \log x \big) = d \big( \log r \big)  + i \, d\theta $$

Then it suggests that these one-forms are computing [angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle), but what could the wedge of two angles means $d\theta \wedge d\phi $ ?  So there are a few questions swirling around my mind.

---

This is a fairly algebraic question as no limits are being taken... My main question is **not** how are the homology groups computed, at this moment, I am only interested in building the de Rham chain complex for $\mathbb{C}P^2$.

Comment: Do you know the definition of these objects, $\Omega^k(\cdot)$? If so, can you think of an example of a nonconstant function on $R^n$? How about a function which is not of the form $f(x_1)$?

Comment: @MoisheCohen Thank you for reminding me.  The exercise here is to remember what the chain complexes are for computing the de Rham cohomology of $H^*(\mathbb{C}P^2)$.  Even the statement that $d^2 = 0$ leads to a differential equation on complex projective space.

Comment: My suggestion is to pick up a textbook covering diff forms and read carefully the definitions of differential forms, examples, etc.

Comment: @MoisheCohen From the [welcome](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) page: "Mathematics Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for people studying math at any level and professionals in related fields. "

Comment: I really don't think you've fully appreciated the fact that, for example, $x$ is not a *function* on complex projective space. For example, $\log(x)$ doesn't make sense at all. Also, I'm pretty sure $\mathrm{d}x/x$ isn't a differential form.

Comment: One typical approach to avoiding problems is to use two families of variables. Use $(X,Y,Z)$ coordinates when you really do want to work with homogeneous forms, but define $x = X/Z$ and $y = Y/Z$ and work with $(x,y)$ when you want to write things that are manifestly *functions*.

Comment: An alternate systematic approach is to take the cone; take the map $\mathbb{A}^3(\mathbb{C}) \setminus \{ (0,0,0) \} \to \mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{C})$ given by sending $(a,b,c) \mapsto (a:b:c)$. Then $(x,y,z)$ is referring to coordinates on $\mathbb{A}^3(\mathbb{C}) \setminus \{ (0,0,0) \}$. Note, for example, that things like $x$ or $\log(x)$ cannot be expressed as the pullback of a function on $\mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{C})$. (but the function $x/z$, on its domain, can be expressed as a pullback)

Comment: $\mathbb{CP}^2$ is indeed real four dimensional, and you are confusing yourself between real and complex coordinates.

Comment: @hurkyl this is why you need sheaves

Comment: @cactus314: I don't see how you mean to apply sheaves to solve the problem I bring up. I think you're thinking of a completely orthogonal problem: for example, how to study of $\mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{C})$ in terms of the three affine patches isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^2(\mathbb{C})$ using $(x/z, y/z)$, $(x/y, z/y)$, and $(y/x, z/x)$-coordinates respectively.

Comment: @hurkyl the sheaf of smooth functions, or continuous function or rational functions. and a few others.